# Сохранение сайтов

Tags: веб-программирование

Привет всем.

Есть большой список сайтов. Как их сохранить, не заходя на каждый?

**P.S.** Нужно именно сохранить, чтоб была возможность смотреть их оффлайн.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что речь о поиске программы, которая это может сделать? Или о написании?

Comment: Когда-то давно использовал Teleport Pro.

Comment: В той или иной мере вам придется их "просмотреть" т.к. для сохранения локально их придется скачать, что в целом (в большинстве случаев) равносильно просмотру.

Answer (score 2):

Есть такие программы которые называются веб краулеры. Самые известные из бесплатных это httrack и heritrix. Есть попроще в плане юзабилити но платный offline explorer. Но у всех у них есть проблемы - если часть контента отдается через ссылки генерируется JavaScript'ом он загружен не будет.

Answer (score 2):

Можно написать небольшой BASH скрипт. Алгоритм такой: 
1. Качаем sitemap.xml 
2. берем из него все ссылки 
3. Далее многопоточно грабим сайт собирая все и вся что найдем укладывая на диск.

```
URL_PARSE=$1
MODE=$2
echo "parse: $URL_PARSE"
if test $MODE = "sitemap"
then
    echo "parse: sitemap"
     #Собрать и сохранить из SITEMAP
     curl  http://$URL_PARSE  | grep "<[/]*loc>" | sed 's/[<][/]*loc[>]//g;s/^[ \t]*//' > urls
fi

if test $MODE = "page"
then
     #Собоать и сохранить с обычной страницы
     lynx -listonly -dump $URL_PARSE | grep -oP 'http.?://\S+'  > urls
fi

echo "parse: $URL_PARSE"
xargs -P 20 -n 1 wget -nv -p < urls
```

Юзаьть так: 
`sh save.sh <target-site>/sitemap.xml sitemap`

1 ПРоблема слабенькие сайты будут падать =( Но если выкачивать норм проекты то все ок

Comment: Зачем, если есть wget с рекурсивным обходом?

Comment: Я согласен когда скорость выполнения не является приоритетом то можно и так, последовательно собрать все что будет найдено `wget -nv -r <target-site>` . Просто по моей практике проблема как раз была в критичности времени исполнения и если ресурс имеет кк страниц можно бесконечно долго ждать , а так какждый URL заворачтвается в отдельный thr и независимо скачивается , что дает существенный прирост во времени выполнения

Comment: @redriod Ах, да, не обратил внимание, что многопоточный скрипт)