# Как извлечь файлы из Wordpress CMS

Tags: html, wordpress, cms

Вопрос такой:Wordpress CMS установлен.FTP cpanel wp admin т.д все имеется как сделать чтобы нормально было все html css js т.д не хочу CMS

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/598049/186083 а потом offline версию используете как статичный сайт.

Comment: Я не понял там что,как помогите?